# Drupal initial setup on linux?

Tags: linux, drupal

I'm trying to setup a Drupal test site.  I'm a .Net developer, so I don't have a lot of experience with Linux machines.  Can anyone tell me, for a test site of Drupal what the initial setup would be for:

1. CPU
2. RAM
3. Storage size
4. Storage mount points

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal systems requirements, have a look at: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements

If you just want te test Drupal without the fuss of setting up things from scratch, try one of these options:

For quickly testing Drupal and contributed modules online, without needing to setup anything, try: https://simplytest.me

To get a free test developer account with easy Drupal install in the cloud, try using: https://insight.acquia.com/free/register

If you have access to a windows pc or mac, you can quickly setup a local development environment for Drupal using Acquia dev desktop: https://dev.acquia.com/downloads

If you are happy to host your own test Drupal site on shared hosting, you can also get a hosing account like https://www.dreamhost.com use their on-click install feature to install Drupal for testing purposes.

Comment: thanks for that! any idea about how much storage and mount points for setting up a local machine?